# Formats for .edi, .seq and .xls

Tags: symfony, validation, format, mime-types, symfony-forms

I'm using the Form Builder from Symfony and the class I created for the Form is like the next:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class Upload

{

    /**
     * @Assert\File(
     *     maxSize = "4000k",
     *     mimeTypes = {"text/plain", "text/xml", "application/xml", "text/csv", 
     *                  "application/EDI-consent", "application/EDIFACT", "application/EDI-X12"
     *                  "application/vnd.mseq", "application/json-seq", 
     *                  "application/vnd.sealed-xls", 
     *                  "application/pdf", "application/x-pdf",
     *                  "application/zip"},
     *     mimeTypesMessage = "Please upload a valid format file"
     *     )
     * @var file
     */
     protected $file;

     ...
```

I need to accept these next extensions:
**'txt,dat,xml,csv,edi,seq,xls,pdf,zip'**

Is enough like this? Is anything left to add? I'm wrong with something?

Symfony Docs recommend to get the results from here:

https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion it should work properly. Maybe you should add **application/octet-stream** and **zz-application/zz-winassoc-dat** to match also [dat file extension](http://www.whatisfileextension.com/dat/). And... test your code with different files in order to see if it works.